# How to stop child's drag event from triggering Parent's drag event

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, sortablejs

I see numerous questions asking the other way around: How to stop child events when the parent is acted upon.

I'm making a form builder with nested drag-and-drop functionality. Sections are draggable amonst themselves, questions are draggable within and between sections, and questions can have multiple options that are draggable within and between questions.

I'm using [SortableJS](https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable) for the sorting functionality, and as far as I can tell, I have the bottom level set up exactly like the other two, but for some reason trying to drag an option triggers `ondragstart` for its parent question.

I've tried `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()` for the `ondragstart` of the options, but those don't allow any dragging at all, whether of the option or its parent question.

Somehow the ondragstart is translating up from the option into the question, where it doesn't do that from the question up into its section.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/robertgreenstreet/h8ocmL2p/4/